# Bash, put a space after a specific coma

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I get a file where every line is of the form

```
sentence1, sentence2, sentence3, sentence4,sentence5, ....
```

I would like to write a script to put a space after the fourth coma. I have tried sed and awk,  but I am not involved with regular expression and even reading some doc, I don't succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sed

```
sed 's/,/, /4' yourfile
```